# AngularJS nested ng-bind on elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bind

Think I'm missing something simple here but here's my issue:

```
 <h4 ng-bind="example.heading">
  <small ng-bind="example.subheading"></small>
 </h4>
```

Doesn't work - if `ng-bind` replaces the content inside the tag, then would I have to use the `{{}}` syntax instead? Like so,

```
<h4>{{example.heading}}<small ng-bind="example.subheading"></small></h4>
```

I like the idea of the brackets not flashing up briefly so I picked `ng-bind`. Is there another way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prevent the brackets from flashing, use `ng-cloak` to hide compiling Angular:

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-cloak>
    <h4>{{example.heading}}<small ng-bind="example.subheading"></small></h4>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ng-cloack` is the solution.

Dont forget to add the following css if you want to use it

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Good point to note. I'm using MeanJS so that's already included.